# Subtraction between two dates in Powershell is evaluating to null

Tags: powershell, date, difference, days

I am using the following code to display some values , the subtraction between two dates as in the expression
[datetime]::Now.AddDays(-365) - $_.PasswordLastSet).Days

is evaluating to null in my data, what could be the reason, how to fix this code ?

```
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties PasswordLastSet, Mail -SearchBase $searchBase |                                          
    Where-Object{ 
        ([datetime]::Now.AddDays(-365) - $_.PasswordLastSet).Days -in @(" ",364, 350, 354, 340, 335,' ','',"")
    }|
      Select-Object name, PasswordLastSet,@{n='DaysUntilExpired';e={(([datetime]::Now.AddDays(365) - [datetime]::$_.PasswordLastSet).Day).days}} |
    Add-Content -Path C:\Temp\PasswordExpList.txt
```

Comment: When attempting to cast, use `[datetime]$_`. `[datetime]::$_` does nothing because `::` is a class static operator. Also, maybe there is a typo because `[datetime]::as` is nothing

Comment: Actually yes it is not AS in the code it should be NOW as in                                                            Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties PasswordLastSet, Mail -SearchBase $searchBase |                                          
    Where-Object{ 
        ([datetime]::Now.AddDays(-365) - $_.PasswordLastSet).Days -in @(" ",364, 350, 354, 340, 335,' ','',"")
    }|
      Select-Object name, PasswordLastSet,@{n='DaysUntilExpired';e={(([datetime]::Now.AddDays(365) - [datetime]::$_.PasswordLastSet).Day).days}} |
    Add-Content -Path C:\Temp\PasswordExpList.txt

Answer (score 0):

There are two obvious bugs in your code, both here:

```
@{n='DaysUntilExpired';e={(([datetime]::Now.AddDays(365) - [datetime]::$_.PasswordLastSet).Day).days}}
```

However, I can't tell if you should specify this:

```
@{n='DaysUntilExpired';e={([datetime]::Now.AddDays(365) - $_.PasswordLastSet).Days}}
```

Or, if you're looking for the last day of the month prior to the expiration date, then this:

```bsh
@{n='DaysUntilExpired';e={(([datetime]::Now.AddDays(365) - $_.PasswordLastSet.Day).Days}}
```

As the comments mention, `[datetime]::$_.PasswordLastSet` is nonsense. That's the first bug. The second one is that the property of a timespan is `Days`, not `Day`. `Day` is a property of a datetime.

---

However, assuming you're trying to calculate the password expiration date defined by AD password policy, you should look at the `msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed` property in AD because that's what that property contains. You have to convert it from a large integer date, but that's what `[datetime]::fromfiletime()` does.

```bsh
Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties PasswordLastSet, Mail, 'msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed' -SearchBase $searchBase |
Select-Object -Properties Name, PasswordLastSet, @{n='PasswordExpirationDate';e={[DateTime]::FromFileTime($_.'msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed')}}
```

This doesn't do everything your script does, but then I don't understand why you're looking for accounts whose password was set an exact number of days in the past. That doesn't seem useful.